# Introduction on Opencv and JavaCV

Tags: java, opencv, javac, javacv

What is OpenCv and JavacV? please give simple introduction or meaning.Please tell me how useful in programming language.

Comment: Please use google for questions like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenCV is a library that is used for computer vision applications. It is originally made for C/C++.  JavaCV is a Java implementation of the same API.  What are you planning to use it for?  If you only know Java you may be able to make due with JavaVC.  If you plan to work on an embedded system OpenCV is definitely the way to go.  I hear Khronos will soon be releasing an early version of OpenVX which is a hardware accelerator for OpenCV.

Here is the OpenCV API: http://docs.opencv.org/index.html

Comment: Actually I build video processing programm in hadoop framework with java language....In this program opencv and javacv used

Comment: please provide me link in which opencv command like opencvFrameGrabber , opencvframerecoder

Answer (score 3):

> JavaCV is designed so that most OpenCV functions can be used in JavaCV in the exact same way as they would in C/C++ code. However there are many functions that need to be treated differently, such as when a pointer to a struct needs to be passed to OpenCV.

Ex:

OpenCV Code:

```
int i = cvRound(f);
```

JavaCV Equivalent:

```
int i = (int)Math.round(f);
```

https://code.google.com/p/javacv/wiki/ConvertingOpenCV

Comment: please provide me link in which opencv command like opencvFrameGrabber , opencvframerecoder